# PHP only remove commas from numbers in this associative array?

Tags: php, associative-array

What is the best method to remove commas from numbers in the associative array below? Keep the commas in text, thanks.

$main_arr contains the following 3 arrays:

```
Array
(
    [phrase] => Hi, I'm ok
    [number_a] => 3,575
    [number_b] => 64
    [number_c] => 8,075
)
 
Array
(
    [phrase] => Bye, it's late
    [number_a] => 7,365
    [number_b] => 32
    [number_c] => 648,120
)
 
Array
(
    [phrase] => Good catch!
    [number_a] => 11,659
    [number_b] => 128
    [number_c] => 1,492,352
```

Comment: Check if key contains "number" and replace comma.

Comment: more helpful if there was code to see how to loop through the assoc-array and update the values

Comment: @Level1Coder But we assume you must have tried something.

Comment: More helpful was usable code or at least a try where you are stuck. Use var_export() instead of print_r(). Here is not clear, if you are having multiple arrays or just one.

Comment: these 3 arrays are within a $main_arr

Comment: Please update the question even it answered, already, and use var_export() for the array. Nobody wants to recreate it manually providing an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    <?php
    $mainArray =[
         [
            'phrase' => "Hi, I'm ok",
            'number_a' => "3,575",
            'number_b' => "64",
            'number_c' => "8,075",
         ],
         [
          'phrase' => "Bye, it's late",
          'number_a' => "7,365",
          'number_b' => "32",
          'number_c' => "648,120",
         ],
         [
          'phrase' => 'Good catch!',
          'number_a' => "11,659",
          'number_b' => "128",
          'number_c' => "1,492,352",
         ],
   ];
    foreach($mainArray as &$array) {
        foreach($array as &$val) {
           if (preg_match('/^[0-9,]*$/', $val)){
           $val =   str_replace(',','',$val);
         }
     }
 }
    var_export($mainArray);
```

Comment: adjust the pattern as you want

Comment: good work, I was 25 seconds too late......

Comment: thanks for the help, but forgot to mention $main_arr contains the 3 arrays presented here.

Comment: then all you have to do is run one more layer of foreach

Comment: Can @AsmaMech edit answer to add the extra layer of foreach so I can accept the answer? Thanks!